# Rotate Triangle In OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a triangle around it's center point. I'm aware that OpenGL rotates about the origin so I need to translate the middle point to the origin, then rotate, and translate back. I've commented out this last line to ensure that it at least rotates about its center  at the origin. It does not. It appears to be rotating about its old origin despite the translation... Note that ccc4 and ccp generate floats. Here's my code:

```
ccColor4B colors[] = {
    ccc4(255, 0, 0, 255),
    ccc4(0, 255, 0, 255),
    ccc4(0, 0, 255, 255)
};

CGPoint vertices[] = {
    ccp(0,0),
    ccp(50,100),
    ccp(100,0),
};

CGPoint middle[] = {ccp(50,50)};
CGPoint origin[] = {ccp(0,0)};

// Rotate the triangle
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-50, -50, 0);
glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1.0);
// glTranslatef(50, 50, 0);

// Draw the triangle
glLineWidth(2);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colors);
glColor4ub(0, 0, 255, 255);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3);

// Revert rotation, we only want triangle to rotate 
glPopMatrix();

// Draw the points
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glPointSize(5);
glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, middle);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

glPointSize(5);
glColor4ub(0, 255, 0, 255);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, origin);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
// End points
```

Here's the output:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: My triangle isn't even equilateral now that I noticed. I keep geting sqrt(3)/6 for the center point of an equilateral though...

Comment: Would you happen to have a link to the proof?

Comment: @AramKocharyan: Sorry, I gave you a bum-steer. That's the height of the triangle, not the center. The center which is just 1/3 in the y-axis, as per Vyktor's comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to think of transforms as applying in reverse relative to the order in which you call them.

Actually, it's easier to think in terms of transforming the local coordinate system (LCS), not the object, which allows you to mentally apply transforms in the order they're called. To rotate about the center, translate the LCS to the center, rotate, then translate it back out again:

```
glTranslatef(50, 50, 0);
glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(-50, -50, 0);
```

Comment: Cheers! I'll remember to think in that mindset. It makes sense now. Drawing wrt the LCS means later draws are also wrt this LCS.

Comment: @AramKocharyan: That's correct. It also means that later *transforms* are wrt the LCS. For instance, imagine you start with the identity transform, then call `glScale(20, 20, 20)` followed by `glRotate(45, 0, 0, 1)`. If you then call `glTranslate(1, 0, 0)`, the LCS will move 20 units diagonally up and to the right relative to the world.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo example that makes sense too.

Comment: Would you happen to know why scaling then rotating gives different results from rotating then scaling?

Comment: @AramKocharyan: Unless you are doing another transform in between, or the scaling factors are different for each axis, it shouldn't make any difference. Multiplying by a scale matrix with identical scale factors for each dimension is equivalent to multiplying by a scalar, which is commutative (i.e., `glScale(f, f, f)` can appear anywhere in a chain of transforms).

Comment: @AramKocharyan: Correct. If you rotate first, the scaling applies to the rotated axes.

Comment: A minor point of clarification: when I said "up and to the right" I meant "up" in the y-axis. It's more common to think of the z-axis as being "up/down", while y represents "north/south".

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, hopefully it's useful to others. Yikes it's been 2 years almost!

Comment: @AramKocharyan: I came across it as a result of some badge I got, and, on re-reading, it occurred to me that my explanation wasn't as clear as it could have been.